# Matplotlib hangs during instantiation on Pixelbook

Tags: python, matplotlib, chromebook

I am trying to set up a python3 development environment on my Pixelbook.
I enabled native linux app support on it by switching to developer branch, so now I have a working bash shell with apt.

I was able to install gvim and python3.5.3 and pip.  I installed numpy, scipy, pandas and matplotlib fine. All the other packages work smoothly, and I can import matplotlib, but as soon as I try to call any method from matplotlib it hangs my shell and never returns.
Here is a simple scripts I use for testing:

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
t = sp.arange(0, 10, 1/100)
plt.plot(t, sp.sin(1.7 * 2 * sp.pi * t) + sp.sin(1.9 * 2 * sp.pi * t))
plt.show()
```

I try to run it like this, but it never returns and Ctrl+C doesn't help either:
[Command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tldwj.png)
I tried using a different backend like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

It doesn't help either.

Some people suggest using `matplotlib.ion()`, but it didn't change anything either.
I found [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/comments/8pxsne/matplotlib_showing_plots/) where someone was also having a hard time using matplotlib on a pixelbook.

The solution proposed there was to install spyder, so I did, like this:

```
sudo pip3 install -U spyder
```

This didn't help either.
It seems to me that matplotlib cannot find the graphics back end on my machine.  I am running crouton and as I mentioned before gvim installed just fine.  This is after the google announcement of support of linux native apps on chromebooks, so I am not running in a VM, this is stock chrome os moved to dev branch and switched to enable linux.

I am wondering if I need additional X11 backend installed separately, but I checked google documentation for installing Android Studio on Pixelbook, and it didn't mention any additional graphics installations, just "enable linux and install the linux tgz package".  I would really appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into that problem, I fixed it in a couple of steps.  First, I was having general stability issues with my linux partition after installing a bunch of random junk, so I wiped it and started from scratch by switching to stable branch and then boing back to dev branch and enabling linux.  After that I installed anaconda (instead of using apt to install python).  This gave me a newer version of Python with all the packages I needed and everything worked, including pandas, numpy and matplotlib.

Comment: One thing that was a bit tricky is jupyter notebook.   It wasn't starting correctly, but after a bit of research I discovered that it's because browser coming from Chrome OS was showing as a remote connection and by default jupyter does not allow that, so I had to go to jupyter's config file and enable remote access.  The config file is ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py, and you want to replace the line "c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'" with this c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'.